# Response 400 from Google Vision API OCR with a base64 string of specified image

Tags: python, ocr, google-vision

I've read [How to use the Google Vision API for text detection from base64 encoded image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094048/how-to-use-the-google-vision-api-for-text-detection-from-base64-encoded-image) but it doesn't help at all. [Cloud client library](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text) is undesirable for me because I am doing many image processing (e.g. rotating, cropping, resizing, etc.) before and during OCR. Saving them as new files and re-read them as inputs of Google Vision API is rather inefficient.

Hence, I went check the documentation of posting requests directly:

- [Using Python to send requests](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/using-python)
- [Base64 Encoding](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/base64)
- [Optical character recognition (OCR)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr),

and here are minimum codes to make the failure:

```
import base64
import requests
import io

# Read the image file and transform it into a base64 string
with io.open("photos/foo.jpg", 'rb') as image_file:
    image = image_file.read()
content = base64.b64encode(image)

# Prepare the data for request
# Format copied from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr
sending_request = {
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "content": content
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

# Send the request and get the response
# Format copied from https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/using-python
response = requests.post(
    url='https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key={}'.format(API_KEY),
    data=sending_request,
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
)

# Then get 400 code
response
# <Response [400]>
print(response.text)
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nrequests=image&reque\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I went to my console and see there are indeed request errors for `google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotator.BatchAnnotateImages`, but I don't know what happened. Is it because the wrong format of sent `data` in `requests.post`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error, `"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nrequests=image&reque\n^",` states you are passing a non-json format which is required to be a json. So, you should convert it to json and pass it to the request, as shown below.

```
response = requests.post(
url='https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key={}'.format(API_KEY),
# import json module
# dumps the object to JSON
data=json.dumps(sending_request), 
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```

It will trigger `typeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable at the line of json.dumps([sending_request])` because you are not decoding the b64encode image. So, do this first and send the request

`content = base64.b64encode(image).decode('UTF-8')`

Comment: It triggers `TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable` at the line of `json.dumps([sending_request])`.

Comment: @ytu updated the answer. Also do not dump the json in any array. use **json.dumps(sending_request)** instead of json.dumps([sending_request])

Comment: It works after decoding. Thank you. Before that, neither `json.dumps([sending_request])` nor `json.dumps(sending_request)` worked.